# How to extend authentication in OroCRM

Tags: symfony, orocrm

Good day, everyone.

I need to extend authentication mechanism for my needs.
To do this i created [Custom Form Password Authenticator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_password_authenticator.html)

1) I changed firewall settings

```
    main:
            ...
            #organization-form-login:
            simple_form:
                authenticator:              my_authenticator
                csrf_provider:              form.csrf_provider
                check_path:                 oro_user_security_check
                login_path:                 oro_user_security_login
            ...
```

2) I created service for my_authenticator

```
services:
    ...
    my_authenticator:
        class:     OQ\SecurityBundle\Security\MyAuthenticator
        arguments:
            - @oro_organization.organization_manager
    ...
```

3) And here is the code of MyAuthenticator

```
namespace OQ\SecurityBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
Use Oro\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordOrganizationToken;
use Oro\Bundle\OrganizationBundle\Entity\Manager\OrganizationManager;

class MyAuthenticator implements SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface
{
    /** @var OrganizationManager */
    protected $manager;

    public function __construct(OrganizationManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
    {

        // Here will be my special checks

        //Here i try to get username and force authentication

        try {
            $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($token->getUsername());
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException $e) {
            throw new AuthenticationException('This user not allowed');
        }

        // If everythin' is ok - create a token
        if ($user) {
            return new UsernamePasswordOrganizationToken(
                $user,
                $user->getPassword(),
                $providerKey,
                $this->manager->getOrganizationById(1)
            );
        } else {
            throw new AuthenticationException('Invalid username or password');
        }


    }

    public function supportsToken(TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return $token instanceof UsernamePasswordOrganizationToken
        && $token->getProviderKey() === $providerKey;
    }

    public function createToken(Request $request, $username, $password, $providerKey)
    {
        //UsernamePasswordOrganizationToken
        return new UsernamePasswordOrganizationToken($username, $password, $providerKey, $this->manager->getOrganizationById(1));
    }
}
```

When i try to authenticate user - i succesfully log in, but i dont see anything except black header and profiler. Profiler says me, that i'm logged as USER_NAME (yellow color), and not authenticated (red color).
Can you give me an advice - how to make t work?
And one more question - how can i retrieve user's organization in this authenticator class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check UsernamePasswordToken constructor you'll see it requires you to pass $roles in order to make it authenticated
`parent::setAuthenticated(count($roles) > 0);`

And it's impossible to change authenticate flag after in setAuthenticated (see the code why).

Check also UserAuthenticationProvider class to get an idea what's happening.

I hope this helps.

Comment: ThatsIt!
I didnt specified user role because this parameter is optional in UsernamePasswordOrganizationToken. Now it works, thank you!